# How to handle user revoking LinkedIn access in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, omniauth, linkedin-api

How should I handle a user revoking my access to their LinkedIn account? I am using Ruby on Rails with `Omniauth`, `Omniauth-LinkedIn` and `linkedin` gem (latter incorporates `oauth` gem).

My controller code

```
if !@user[:lnk_token].nil?
  client = LinkedIn::Client.new("xxxx","xxxx")
  client.authorize_from_access(@user[:lnk_token].strip,@user[:lnk_access_token_secret].strip)
  @lnk = client.profile(:fields => ["picture-url", "positions", "educations"])
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple error handler:

```
if !@user[:lnk_token].nil?
  client = LinkedIn::Client.new("xxxx","xxxx")
  client.authorize_from_access(@user[:lnk_token].strip,@user[:lnk_access_token_secret].strip)
  begin
    @lnk = client.profile(:fields => ["picture-url", "positions", "educations"])
  rescue
    @lnk = nil
  end
end
```

Further reading: http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html